# Combinatorics problem involving placing balls into bags

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

There are $r$ red balls and $w$ white balls, and $n$ bags. Each bag has to have at least one white and red ball in. In how many ways can we place these balls into the bags?

*My solution*: 
Place one white and one red ball into the $n$ bags. We then have $w-n$ and $r-n$ white and red balls respectibely. There are $n \choose w-n$ ways of placing the white balls, and $n\choose r-n$ ways of placing the red balls, so there are ${n \choose r-n}{n \choose w-n}$ ways.

Comment: good start.  To finish, use [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: why does my method not work though? I've used stars and bars in my comment below

Comment: Well, why should it?  You are only counting the ways to place your surviving $w-n$ white balls (say) assuming no bag gets more than one of them.  Suppose I just throw them all in the first bag?

Comment: ah of course thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nope, sorry, not totally right. Your idea is good, just the numbers in the end are wrong. Assume for example $n = 2$ bags and $w=r= 20$ balls of each color. Then you would have ${2 \choose 18}{2 \choose 18} = 0$ possibilities, and I don't think you want that. :)

So if you find the right formula for putting the remaining balls in the bags then this should work.

Comment: ahh yeh i get it, so say each n-r is coded as x, and each bag is coded as y. Then if we have a chain xxx...yyyy..., with r-n x's and n-1 y's, the number of combinations of these is the same as (r-n+n-1)!/(n-1)!(r-n)! =(r-1)c(n-1). We do the same with the whites by symmetry so the total combinations are (r-1)c(n-1) *(w-1)c(n-1) ? And i get why my first method doesn't work like by you example  but why doesn't it actually work?